# C++ behavior that I don't understand

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, c++17, implicit-conversion

My friends and I were playing with the C++ language. While doing so, we encountered something we couldn't understand.

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::vector<char> const &input)
{
    std::cout << input.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << input.at(i) << " - ";
    }

}

int main()
{
    char cha = 'A';
    char chb = 'B';
    char * pcha = &cha;
    char * pchb = &chb;
    try
    {
        std::vector<char> a = {pcha, pchb};
        //std::vector<char> a = {pchb, pcha};
        print(a);

    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Output for this code:

> A

When I comment out this first line try block and uncomment the second line, which comes to this:

```
try
{
    // std::vector<char> a = {pcha, pchb};
    std::vector<char> a = {pchb, pcha};
    print(a); 
}
```

Output becomes:

> std:exception

I thought maybe the this occurs because of the different padding and alignments of the declared variables (char, char*), yet still didn't understand. You can find the code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/H1cc5oweU) to play around.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) then [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: Try to summarize "the behavior that could not be understood" in the title; as of now the title has little use to others.

Comment: You later should read [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) draft of C++17 standard. And understand what [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means. Try to use the [`gdb` debugger](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: "we encountered something we couldn't understand." <- Lucky you, I encounter many things I can't understand :-P

Comment: Depending on what was *expected* with the syntax, this may be relevant: https://foonathan.net/2016/12/fixing-initializer-list/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<char> a = {pcha, pchb};
> ```

Here, you use the constructor of vector that accepts two iterators to a range. Unless the end iterator is reachable from the begin one, the behaviour of the program is undefined. Your two pointers are not iterators to the same range (i.e. elements of an array), so one is not reachable from the other. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

These would be correct:

```
std::vector<char> a = {cha, chb}; // uses initializer_list constructor

// or
char arr[] {cha, chb};
char * pcha = std::begin(arr);
char * pchb = std::end(arr);
std::vector<char> a = {pcha, pchb}; // uses the iterator constructor
```

Comment: Initialization lists strike again.. :|

Comment: Vector constructor(s): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: Personally I tend to recommend people not try to their luck with hitting the correct `std::vector` initializer, and suggest that they default-initialize; reserve; and fill it up with a back-inserter or back-emplacer.

Comment: @einpoklum: That leads to pretty ugly code. The principle problem here is intent, and the OP's intent is simply confused.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Agree regarding OP's intent. But TBH, whenever I see an `std::vector` being initialized with one or two values - I always get this bad feeling.

Answer (score 2):

@eerorika's answer explains your mistake.

However, I would like to dissuade you, and other readers, from using the second part of the  his(?) corrected code snippet - not because it's incorrect, but because it's problematic coding practice:

1. I accept Nicolai Jossutis' [suggestion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) of trying to uniformly initialize variables with curly brackets and no equals since (e.g.. `mytype myvar {my_initializer};`).
2. Freestanding pointers are dangerous beasts. Try to avoid them altogether, or minimize their existence to where you really need them. After all, you were "tempted" to use those pointers in an inappropriate way... so,

   ```
   char arr[] {cha, chb};
   std::vector<char> a = {std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)};
   ```
3. Don't create a dummy container just to create the one you really want. Just stick with the first line in @eerorika's suggestion (without the equals sign):

   ```
   std::vector<char> a {cha, chb};
   ```
4. In fact, unless you really need it - you probably don't even want to create a variable-length container. So perhaps just

   ```
   std::array<char, 2> a {cha, chb};
   ```

   or with C++17's template argument deduction:

   ```
   std::array a {cha, chb};
   ```